# how does code determine to use WebSphereRequestUpgradeStrategy vs TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy?

Tags: java, websocket, websphere-liberty, java-websocket

I'm trying to use websockets and my spring app runs on Websphere Liberty. My Websockets connection does not work, and upon debugging with class libraries, I figured out that my code goes to `TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy` and this one does not work, versus the one that uses `WebSphereRequestUpgradeStrategy` works fine. Am not clear on how does the logic to determine this work? I have set spring-boot-starter-tomcat as provided in my pom. So am not clear how it is causing it to use TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy. Can someone help me with this?

Working:

```
SRTServletRequest31.upgrade(Class<T>) line: 157 
WsocHandlerImpl.handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServerEndpointConfig, Map<String,String>, boolean) line: 268 
ServerContainerExt.doUpgrade(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServerEndpointConfig, Map<String,String>) line: 288   
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 62  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 498  
WebSphereRequestUpgradeStrategy.upgradeInternal(ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse, String, List<Extension>, Endpoint) line: 87  
WebSphereRequestUpgradeStrategy(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy).upgrade(ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse, String, List<WebSocketExtension>, Principal, WebSocketHandler, Map<String,Object>) line: 119    
DefaultHandshakeHandler(AbstractHandshakeHandler).doHandshake(ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler, Map<String,Object>) line: 281    
WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 166
```

Not working:

```
SRTServletRequest31.upgrade(Class<T>) line: 157 
RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequestWrapper).upgrade(Class<T>) line: 399   
HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequestWrapper).upgrade(Class<T>) line: 399 
HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequestWrapper).upgrade(Class<T>) line: 399  
UpgradeUtil.doUpgrade(WsServerContainer, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServerEndpointConfig, Map<String,String>) line: 234   
WsServerContainer.doUpgrade(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ServerEndpointConfig, Map<String,String>) line: 265    
TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy.upgradeInternal(ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse, String, List<Extension>, Endpoint) line: 72 
TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy(AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy).upgrade(ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse, String, List<WebSocketExtension>, Principal, WebSocketHandler, Map<String,Object>) line: 119   
DefaultHandshakeHandler(AbstractHandshakeHandler).doHandshake(ServerHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler, Map<String,Object>) line: 281    
WebSocketHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 166
```

Pls let me know if you need more details. Appreciate any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer for my question. This could be helpful for someone else in the future.

`DefaultHandshakeHandler` has a check to see if `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler` is present in the class loader. Since there was tomcat-embed-websocket in the pom dependency, this class was present. So, even though I was running on Liberty, this was getting triggered. Removing the same from the pom, helped me fix the problem.